# Spring injecting interface in multi module project

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

one question for spring developers:

I am working on multi module project using spring framework.

modules:

**parent** (parent maven pom project)

**all** (ear project used to build ear from multiple modules)

**catalog** as parent of

**catalog-ejb** (implementation)

**catalog-api** (interface)

there is also a **rest** module which has dependency to catalog-api
and uses autowired interface from catalog-api.

Problem is that during deployment i get "No qualifying bean of type found" exception.

*api module is deployed as jar library within ear*

*ejb module is deployed as ejbModule*

*rest module is deployed as webModule (war).*

Comment: So you haven't configured your implementation classes as Spring beans? Then it won't work, since Spring cannot see your implementation classes.

Comment: ohh im using spring 4 and my rest module has @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ex.rest", "com.ex.catalog.api"})

rest module caanot see implementation classes directly (this is the purpose of interface)

Comment: Post your POM. You do have to include the implementation package as a runtime dependency or it just won't be there.

Comment: Then how do you expect Spring to create instances of the implementation classes to inject them?

Comment: there is no scope defined for implementation jar under *-all module, so it should be compile, implementation jar is also present in ear deployment. I don't know how spring would find implementations, but i think it should, at the end, all classes are deployed to same jvm at deployment time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was a problem with ejb module packaged as ejb in ear. In result duplicate webinitializers were executed at startup resulting exceptions.

Spring didn't found any implementations because componentscan was assigned to *.api package but implementation is in *.ejb package.